# Call jQuery and other scripts for the entire site collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, master-page, site-collection

I want to be able to use jquery and other javascript files across my entire site collection. If I create a new site, it should already be calling jQuery. I don't want to have to worry about whether this page has it, but some other page does not. I've placed all the scripts I want to use in the Style Library in the Top Level site. I edited the master page (v4) for the top level site. When I create a new site, the v4 used is the default which contains non of my changes and therefore none of the scripts. Is there anyway for me to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

EDIT: I only have client side access and sharepoint designer.

Comment: What method are you using to create your sites? If you are creating them using powershell you can easily set the masterpage as part of the creation script...

Comment: Through the UI using the New sites option.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the new site, change the master page in Site Settings to the proper master page.

If you are working with team sites and not in the publishing realm, you can save a site with your custom master page applied as a template and use this as the template used when creating a new site.

The other alternative is to create a feature receiver that detects when a new site is created and swaps out the master page.

Comment: Manually changing the master page for every new site sounds incredibly tedious. I think I'll have to go with the template option, which isn't ideal either but at least somewhat of a solution